# Grails run-app with weird error

Tags: grails

I'm trying to run a project that I didn't create originally and following the given instructions, everything goes fine up to the run-app part. Before this, I was able to grails compile the required plugins, but in the actual app I get this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HD/Users/carloslopez//grails/2/1/1/
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HD.Users.carloslopez..grails.2.1.1.
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

what might it be trying to look up? I sense the double slash could be bombing everything up, which is weird since the original location of grails is /opt/local/bin/grails-2.1.1

Ideas or suggestions on where to look?

Answer (score 0):

it appears that it's looking for what I'm guessing is an unpacked grails 2.1.1 library on the computer of someone named Carlos Lopez. If that project was build correctly, it only needs the proper grails jar file.

Comment: Here's the full rundown: I unpacked Grails in /opt/... route and try to run the app that I was given. The unpacked (unzipped) grails works ok. So according to you, where should I put the grails jar file?

Comment: What I'd like to know is, why it's looking at HD/Users/carloslopez//grails/2/1/1/ and what's trying to get from there.

Comment: did you unzip the grails jar as well? I typically have grails installed on my system via a neat groovy tool called gvm : http://gvmtool.net/ using that I can invoke grails from any directory in the shell. Are you on windows or a *nix/OSX  ?

Comment: I'm on Mac, but using gvm installed Grails in a hard drive containing spaces in its name, hence, giving a similar error because the path was being cut. I just downloaded the zip, uncompressed it and then was able to compile and install, but not actually run-app

Answer (score 0):

Grails creates its own folder inside /home/ and that ended up caught in the full path containing a whitespace, which was breaking when it was looked up.

Removed the whitespace and reset the home directory and everything went back to working.